# First Match - awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

consider file having values:

```
foo
boo
too
```

and another one:

```
foo,1
foo,2
boo,1 
soo,1
```

How to get only first match from the 2nd file, where output will be:

```
foo,1
boo,1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next} $1 in a {print; delete a[$1]}' file1 file2
foo,1
boo,1
```

Answer (score 6):

A variation of the famous seen idiom.

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=1;next} a[$1]++==1' file1 file2
```

**update**

As @dave_thompson_085 pointed out, there might be multiple `soo,#` in the second file, it cause `a[$1]++==1` to be true for the second one. He also gives several ways to fix it:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=1;next} !--a[$1]' file1 file2
```

Comment: That will wrongly include `soo,2` (if present). Going the other direction works: `FNR==NR{a[$1]=1;next} a[$1]--==1 # or !--a[$1]`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for the heads up, updated.

Answer (score 2):

Not actually `awk`, but it works. And I suppose it allows for easy extension.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
    grep -m1 "$line" "$2"
done < "$1"
```

```
$ ./script.sh file1 file2
```

Took the reading line-by-line from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable.
Then it's just 'find first match with content of line in file2'

Comment: Running `grep` multiple times in the body of a loop can be extremely slow.

Answer (score 2):

I Have also used awk but with different method

command

```
awk -F "," 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){print $0}' file1.txt file2.txt| awk -F "," '{if (!seen[$1]++)print }'
```

output

```
awk -F "," 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){print $0}' file1.txt file2.txt| awk -F "," '{if (!seen[$1]++)print }'
foo,1
boo,1
```